# delete item issue from listview

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a list view filled with data coming from database, i want when i click on an item to

disappear, i used --list.remove(position)-- but i have an error add cast to list.

HERE the list view :

```
    private void populateListViewFromDB() {
    Cursor cursor = db.getAllRecords();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] databaseColumnNames = new String[] { DBAdapter.col_Region };
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursordapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, cursor,
            databaseColumnNames, toViewIDs, FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(myCursordapter);
```

HERE my code when i want to delete an item :

```
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int position, long arg3) {
                 list.remove(position); 
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for responding :)

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: this is not how it works. you have to remove the item from your database.

Comment: no it does not compile !  i don't know why  ??

Comment: and if i just want that the item doesn't appear in the list ? how could i do that ?? thanks for your time

Comment: so there is no solution to make an item disappear without affecting the database !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ListView.remove() method. You should remove correspondent item from the data model and then refresh your adapter.

In your OnItemClickListener listener get the bound data item:

```
Object itemObj = adapter.getItem(position);
```

Then, delete this item from your DB.

Then get new instance of your cursor and update your cursor adapter:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
    adapter.swapCursor(newCurosr);
} else {
    adapter.changeCursor(newCursor);
}
```

Then, notify your list view about data changes:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, how could i do that , could you give me more details please !

Comment: is there a way to solve  that ??! i mean how can i access data model ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You are using using cursor adapter, so your data model is stored in DB. It means you should update your DB and than create new cursor and set it to your adapter.

Comment: thanks a lot for efforts, but what i want just the item to be deleted from list view not from database, all i want if i click on item that he get removed from the list not from database, thanks again for your help

Comment: You should use a kind of filter then. For example, add a column "is_removed" to your DB and select records to your adapter based on the value of this column. Alternatively, do not use cursor adapter and just keep your data model in memory (Have a look at ArrayAdapter, etc)

Comment: thanks man, i will try this solution, i thought that will be a way to make the item removed with just an instruction without using database, but as you said may be this is the only way to make it work.